# How to initiate a phone call in J2me and setting midlet permissions to always allow?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to know how to add permission to allow midlet to initiate a phone call? I am testing my app on nokia E72 where I am always been asked to allow that call. Also, after saying yes it asks whether to initiate a video or a voice call.

I don't want my app to ask any permission and initiate a call straight away. If i could get a trusted third party certificate will it be possible and what permissions I'll have to set and how?

**How to achieve this in J2me?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the security popups you are describing, you will need to sign your app with a certificate from Verisign or Thawte. That'll cost you $299 each year. (Welcome to J2ME).

Comment: Yes! I own that certificate the one from symantec but still its unresolved.

Comment: Afaik Thawte and Verisign are the ones usually recommended, because they are the most widely supported ones. It's quite possible your phone doesn't support apps that are signed by a Symantec certificate.

Comment: Then I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish your app in Nokia OVI store, they will sign it for free and publish it in their store. Even though your app gets signed by Nokia,Verisign and Thawte, the J2ME applications will ask permission from user at least once they do any suspicious actions like SMS , Internet access , Call etc.